# Get string from xml (other than strings.xml)

Tags: android, xml, string

I want to get a string array from other file than strings.xml, because I want my project to be organised.

For example, I have this code:

```
String[] column1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column1);
```

But my string array isn't located in strings.xml, but in \res\values\tables\10.xml

How can I get the string array from that file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about Json objects, XML parsing is too old. you need bring yourself to present

Comment: get the string from such a file like this                                                       String string = getString(R.string.hello);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML files can have arbitrary names, but they need to be located in the values folder. I suggest just calling your file tables10.xml.